# strange css3 error with hover and height expanding

Tags: css, hover, height, transition, expand

I dont know what im doing wrong but obviously its not working... I want to hover the `<li id="photo">` and then the `#sub-menu` should expand its height from `65px` to `130px`

```html
<div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="logo">CAB</div>
        <div class="navigator-line"></div>
        <ul id="nav-bar">
            <li><div class="navigator"></div>ABOUT</li>
            <li><div class="navigator"></div>WEB</li>
            <li><div class="navigator"></div>CORPORATE</li>
            <li id="photo"><div class="navigator"></div>PHOTOGRAPHY</li>
            <li><div class="navigator"></div>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Simple thing but its not running

http://jsfiddle.net/BrVuG/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `#photo:hover #sub-menu` - as the `<li>` is not an ancestor of the sub-menu div .. and in the current context there is no way target `#sub-menu` when hovering over `#photo` as it involves backtracking up the DOM (there is no such combinator supported right now). You can only achieve this effect by targeting a descendant or sibling, but not an ancestor .. you'll see the transition take place if you use a different selector, e.g.

`#nav-wrapper:hover + #sub-menu`

http://jsfiddle.net/BrVuG/2/

In the current context though, what you're trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

*(little additions to what Adrift said...)*

If you really want to do that with the `<li>`, you only have two solutions:

- Put `#sub-menu` inside the `<li>` or after it. Simple enough. I think it's the simpler to do, especially since you have a fixed position and width on `#nav-wrapper`.
- Use javascript (with a mouseover action on the `<li>` that will toggle the width of `#sub-menu`).

Comment: ah! now i understand the problem. the position is fixed so i cant move the content down by itself but why i just cant move the #main-wrapper with a margin or a padding down? because of the same thing adrift said? and my js is terrible i dont know how to do it... :(

Comment: @MarieVondePalme
Sorry for being so late... Yes it's for what Adrift said. You can only target a sibling or child element with CSS selectors. It means that you can do what you want with your `<li>` only if `#nav-wrapper` is inside `#nav-bar` or the said `<li>`... This should do it here.

It has nothing to do with the position being fixed. What I meant is that since you have a fixed position, where you put it, it will always be at the same place on the page. So you can totally move it so you can target it with the `:hover` on the `<li>`, without it affecting its position.